# How to migrate a CRM database to an other? Manually or with an ETL solution?

Tags: database, data-migration

I would like to migrate a database:
- from Goldmine 5.0 - SQL Server 2000 (more than 10 years old, huge quantity of datas)
- to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 - SQL Server 2005

ETL solutions so far I tested some of them don't seems to be that user-friendly has it is said because it is an out-dated release of Goldmine.

I also found "How-To's" to do it manually, and it seems to be "easier" to proceed this way.

The problem for me is that I can't found on the internet clear solutions with the factor "Goldmine 5.0".

I'm just looking for the safier way to do it properly by myself (that is the second problematic factor).

Thank You